# Has anyone implemented a tablesort with ajax?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I would like to sort on a column with a round trip but no page reload. The table is very large and has to be paged in, which I am doing manually with an ajax select element. I know TableSort is available to extend the query but I've only seen examples that reload the page.

Comment: First, why would you need AJAX if you already have the table data? And secondly, how does this pertain to Drupal specifically? Seems like you might have better luck on one of the other SE sites.

Comment: I updated the question with a bit more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use Views module to display your data? Views already has AJAX paging, sorting and filtering.

Comment: I would have to integrate my entity with views to do that. Does views create a TableSort-extended output? I don't use Views that much in custom modules.

Comment: What do you mean "TableSort-extended"?

Views provides table sorting and it can be done by AJAX out off the box.

Comment: Tablesort is a Drupal query extender - not just "sorted table" in general. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!tablesort.inc/class/TableSort/7

Comment: For what purpose do you need "Tablesort"?
If you want allow users to sort table rows by clicking on their headers - then views can do it for you.
If you use Views module - you do not need use Drupal query manually.

Comment: If I wanted to use views, I would have to do all the work of integrating my entity with views. I'm not interested in views.

Comment: Update: I decided to use views :)

Answer (score 1):

here you go mate:

[ajax table sorting](http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/05/ajax-sorted-and-paged-tables-in-drupal-7)